# Inheritance from the objects themselves

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design

Making new inheritance hierarchy with the help of C++ I think about:

> Why there is no inheritance from the class objects? Abstract example (on abstract C++):
>
> ```
> struct Foo { int v; Foo(int a) : v(a) {} };
> struct Buz : public Foo(2) { ... }
> ```
>
> So, the `Buz` is inherited only from instance of `Foo` - `Foo(2)`.

Can such idea be useful? Is there any possible implementations or related ideas?

Comment: What would that even *mean*?

Comment: I think he's asking if a subclass can provide constants to parent-class constructors.

Comment: If you have `template <int N> struct Foo {};`  you could do `struct Buz : Foo<2> {};`. The different instantiations of `Foo` would be unrelated to each other, but you could always give them a common base. Note that `N` is a compile-time constant here, so you can use it for things like array sizes and template metaprogramming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ has what you're describing, but the initialization is done as part of the constructor:

```
struct Buz : public Foo {
  Buz() : Foo(2) { ... };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any possible implementations or related ideas?

Many languages that use prototype inheritance do things like this.

The issue you run into is that from a logic point of view, the concept is only useful in very dynamic languages where 'inheritance' doesn't mean much and the syntax is shorthand for 'put all the fields from X into Y' or in pure languages without mutable variables. If the language allows mutability even if you inherit from `Foo(2)` that doesn't mean it won't be `Foo(3)` tomorrow or that two `Foo(2)` instances are even equivalent - which runs you into issues when you try to see if `Buz` inherits from `Foo(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this using templates.

`template <int n>`

```
 
class Foo
{
public:
  int _n;
  Foo():_n(n){}

};

class Der : public Foo
{
public:
  Der(){};
};

int main()
{
  Foo a;
  Der d;
  return 0;
};
```